# How can I know if a pile in "Grundy's game" have a winning strategy?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

Assume that I'm playing [Grundy's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundy%27s_game) and I have pile of $n$ coins.
I want to know if I have a winning strategy (no matter what is it). **How can I know if there is?**

I understand the transform to [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) heap, but I don't understand how it can tell me if there is a winning strategy or not:
For example: Wikipedia says that pile of 18 equals to [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) heap at size 4, but if I have one pile at Nim, no matter what the size is - I can win at the first move.

So my question is: **for a pile of size $n$ at Grundy's game how can I know if there a winning strategy or not?** (for any size of pile) and if someone can explain me the idea of transform it to [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) heap it will be great (as I said - I don't understand the transform idea, because pile of any size at [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) have a winning strategy).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to know what it means to say that a Grundy game with 18 tokens is equivalent to a Nim heap of size 4.  Imagine you have two tables, one playing the Grundy game with a single 18 token pile, and one playing Nim with a single 4 token pile.  One player makes a legal move on one of the games, and then the other player makes a move on either the same game or the other game, and so on.  (That's the combination in combinatorial game theory.)  Since those two games are equivalent, we can conclude that the second player will always be able to win by making a balancing move on the game that the first player did not choose for their move.

So, just like Nim, you win in Grundy's game if the nim-sum of nimbers of all the piles is not equal to 0, and you win by making a move that leaves the nim-sum equal to 0.  Here is the list of nim-values of single piles (from the wiki):

[image]

We can see that 3 and 15 both have a nim-value of 1.  So if we split the pile of 18 into 3 and 15, the nim-sum left to our opponent is $1+1=0$, so they will lose if we keep up with optimal play.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So if I understand you right: 1. to $18$ there is a winning strategy because $n(18)>0$, right? 2. if I have two piles: $4,6$, so $n(4)+n(6)=0+1=1>0$ so I have winning strategy? 3. It's addition like addition of Nim piles? Thanks!

Comment: @CS1 That's right.  For bonus points, you can see from the table that the winning moves from 4 and 6 would be splitting the 4 into 3 and 1 or splitting the 6 into 4 and 2.

Comment: Thank you, so if I have a pile of $20$ or $7$ there is no winning strategy?

Comment: @CS1 Not if your opponent plays optimally.  But just because your opponent has a winning strategy doesn't  mean that they know what it is.  So you could split 20 into 17 and 3 and hope for the best.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My question (actually is the original) - there is a way to know if pile with $n$ coins **don't** have a winning strategy? (like you wrote at the last paragraph at your answer, but this was about 3 and 15).

Comment: @CS1, There is a Nim pile size where the next player doesn't have a winning strategy: size $0$. When Matthew Daly said "you win...if the nim-sum...is not equal to 0", that's an if-and-only-if: you don't have a winning strategy when the nim-sum *is* equal to $0$.

Comment: @MarkS. thank you for your answer but I'm asking about a pile at size that is bigger then $0$ of course :)

Comment: @CS1 I'm a little confused now: if your question is now fully answered (since you accepted Matthew Daly's answer), great! If not, I'm not sure what your remaining question is, and it might be worth asking as a new question on the site. If you're asking: "Without looking at a table of values, is there an efficient way to know which heap sizes in Grundy's game have a winning strategy for the next player to move?" then the answer is basically "we don't know", but a table has been calculated up to $2^{35}$.

Comment: @MarkS. I think he answered me (this is why I ask here at the comments). Can you give me an example for a pile size bigger then $0$ that there is no winning strategy for it? Thank you!

Comment: @CS1 In Nim, it doesn't exist. In Grundy's Game, "you don't have a winning strategy when the nim-sum is equal to 0.", so based on the table in Matthew Daly's post, 1,2,4,7,10,and 20 are all examples.