# Question about winning and loosing positions at "Grundy's game"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

As a continue to this question: [How can I know if a pile in "Grundy's game" have a winning strategy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172845/how-can-i-know-if-a-pile-in-grundys-game-have-a-winning-strategy):

I'm talking about ["Grundy's game"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundy%27s_game).

I understand from the answer that if I have one pile of $20$ is loosing position because $n(20)=0$,
but if I split it to $19,1$ , I get: $n(19)+n(1) = 3>0$ - and this winning
position.

So my question is: how I can know if I have winning strategy or not?
Assume that is my turn now and I have one pile of $20$, I can win or not?
If yes, what is me next move?

Thank you!

Comment: You can win starting with a single heap of $20$ but only if your opponent plays badly.  Faced with a heap of $19$ and a heap of $1$ they should split the $19$ to $8+11$ or $5+14$ and if they do not then you will have a winning strategy

Comment: So, I don't understand, at pile of $20$ I have winning strategy? (no matter what  the 2nd player does).
Thank you!

Comment: No - with a single heap of $20$ and an opponent who plays optimally, you cannot win with any strategy.  But if they play badly then you can win. You asked "I can win or not?"

Answer (score 2):

> I understand from the answer that if I have one pile of 20 is loosing position because $n$(20)=0,
> but if I split it to 19,1 , I get: $n(19)+n(1)=3>0$ - and this winning position.

It is important to understand what "winning position" and "losing position" mean. These terms are relative to the player to move, not relative to yourself.

"Winning position" means that the *player to move* can win.

"Losing position" means that the *player to move* will lose.

If it is your move on a pile of 20, and you split 20 into 19,1, it is a winning position (as you calculated), but it is now your opponent's move, which means your opponent is the one winning, not you.

Comment: So if I understand you right - I can win if I have a one pile of $20$?

Comment: $n(20) = 0$, so a pile of 20 is a losing position. That means if it is your turn on a pile of 20, then you will lose.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand from the answer that <strike>if I have</strike> one pile of $20$ is loosing position because $n(20)=0$,

This is correct.

> but if I split it to $19,1$ , I get: $n(19)+n(1)=3>0$ - and this winning position.

This is also correct. The two statements are not in contradiction. $[19,1]$ is a winning position *that you are handing to your opponent*. This means your opponent can win, so you lose. A position is "winning" if the person *whose turn it is* has a winning strategy. Being in a winning position is good, but moving to a winning position is bad.